# ASP.NET deployment error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-deployment

I am attempting to deploy a change to a legacy ASP.NET solution. I have copied over the views and css files, but when I try to copy over a modified assembly, I get this error when the application runs:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.dashboard_aspx'.
```

I understand that the site may need to recompile itself, but it is complaining about a view I haven't changed. It is also griping about missing member **InitializeCulture** which I can't even find a reference for in my code.

The site works fine in debug and when deployed locally BTW.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you have the source code not for the view. Have you tried to decompile the assembly and check if it has `InitializeCulture`?

Comment: [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Comment: OK - that is being blocked by IronPort for some random reason so I shall have to download this at home later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I lost patience with trying to deploy what I thought had changed and simply published the website to a directory and then copied that over en masse.

Clearly there is some code or linkage somewhere that I had overlooked but the error message is a complete red herring.